# PhpPowerpoint fatal error

Tags: php, phppowerpoint, phppresentation

I was in the process of viewing an existing pptx file using the reader of Powerpoint2007 but
i get this fatal error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File ./resources/phppowerpoint_logo.gif not found!' in C:\xampp\PHPPresentation-master\src\PhpPresentation\Shape\Drawing.php:107 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\PHPPresentation-master\samples\Sample_Header.php(49): PhpOffice\PhpPresentation\Shape\Drawing->setPath('./resources/php...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\sanagumana.php(8): include_once('C:\xampp\PHPPre...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\PHPPresentation-master\src\PhpPresentation\Shape\Drawing.php on line 107

I already check the resources folder and phppowerpoint_logo.gif is there. What can I do??

Comment: Have you got the last version of the develop branch ?

Comment: i don't know whether this one is the latest. Maybe it's not. Could you send me the link of the latest develop branch? Thanks @Progi1984

Comment: The latest version of the develop branch is here : https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation/archive/develop.zip